# Where can I find C/C++ users journal archive in suitable format (not .html)?

Tags: c++

I am searching for this magazine for quite a long time and I can`t find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they merged with frobbs a couple years ago: http://www.ddj.com/cpp/cuj.jhtml. you might find something there.